# Ruby syntax accept arguments on dynamically generated methods via send

Tags: ruby, syntax, refactoring

How I can pass arguments on dynamically generated methods via send ?

Below I generate on the fly several methods, I want they accept the "row" argument.

The code below generates the methods, but I don't know how let the methods accept the "row" argument.

```
@sql_columns.each do |attr|
  (class << self; self end).send :define_method, attr do
    key = @column_mapping[attr].to_s
    row[key]
  end
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you pass arguments to define_method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89650/how-do-you-pass-arguments-to-define-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(class << self; self end).send :define_method, attr do |row|
```