# What does a double * (splat) operator do

Tags: ruby, splat

Have you seen a function declared like this?

```
def foo a, **b
  ...
end
```

I understand that a single `*` is the splat operator. What does `**` mean?

Answer (score 474, accepted):

Ruby 2.0 introduced keyword arguments, and `**` acts like `*`, but for keyword arguments. It returns a Hash with key / value pairs.

For this code:

```
def foo(a, *b, **c)
  [a, b, c]
end
```

Here's a demo:

```
> foo 10
=> [10, [], {}]
> foo 10, 20, 30
=> [10, [20, 30], {}]
> foo 10, 20, 30, d: 40, e: 50
=> [10, [20, 30], {:d=>40, :e=>50}]
> foo 10, d: 40, e: 50
=> [10, [], {:d=>40, :e=>50}]
```

Comment: This answers the question perfectly, but I had a minor addendum. Just as the splat operator can be used on the array you pass, the double splat can be used on hashes. If `opts = {d: 40, e: 50}`, then `foo 10, opts, f: 60` will assign `{f: 60}` to `c`, whereas `foo 10, **opts, f: 60` will assign `{d: 40, e: 50, f: 60}`. To achieve the second effect, previously you would have `merge`d the arrays explicitly.

Comment: I would assume this is useful for setting optional hash parameters for a method

Comment: Probably worth a note that if mixing keyword-arguments with keyword splat, the keyword splat needs to come after the keyword arguments.

Comment: This does in 10 lines what countless articles fail to do in hundreds. Bravo!

Answer (score 53):

That is the **double splat** operator which is available since Ruby 2.0.

It captures all **keyword arguments** (which can also be a simple hash, which was the idiomatic way to emulate keyword arguments before they became part of the Ruby language)

```
def my_method(**options)
  puts options.inspect
end

my_method(key: "value")
```

The above code prints `{key:value}` to the console.

Just like the single splat operator captures all regular arguments, but instead of an *array* you get a *hash*.

**Real-life example:**

For example in Rails the `cycle` method looks like this:

```
def cycle(first_value, *values)
  options = values.extract_options!
  # ...
end
```

This method can be called like this: `cycle("red", "green", "blue", name: "colors")`.

This is quite a common pattern: You accept a list of arguments and the last one is an options hash, which can be extract - for example - using ActiveSupport's `extract_options!`.

In Ruby 2.0 you can simplify these methods:

```
def cycle(first_value, *values, **options)
  # Same code as above without further changes!
end
```

Admittedly it's only a minor improvement if you are already using ActiveSupport but for plain Ruby the code gains quite a lot of conciseness.

Answer (score 41):

In addition, you can use it in caller side like this:

```
def foo(opts); p opts end
bar = {a:1, b:2}

foo(bar, c: 3)
=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)

foo(**bar, c: 3)
=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

Comment: Wow, double-splat is analagous to ES6's object spread operator.

Comment: Thanks, that's the confirmation I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, the above answers are accurate.

However, double splat operators can also be used in Ruby language for arithmetic operations as well. For example, `x^y` can be written as `x**y`.

Refer to this [stackover question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987339/ruby-double-star-operator#:%7E:text=In%20Ruby%2C%20**%20is%20the,no%20spaces%20between%20the%20operands.) for more.