# What is the point of using Ruby's double-splat (`**`) in method calls?

Tags: ruby, syntax, double-splat

With a single splat, we can expand an array into multiple arguments, which is pretty different from passing the array directly:

```
def foo(a, b = nil, c = nil)
  a
end

args = [1, 2, 3]

foo(args)  # Evaluates to foo([1, 2, 3]) => [1, 2, 3]
foo(*args) # Evaluates to foo(1, 2, 3)   => 1
```

With keyword arguments however, I can't see any difference, since they are just syntactic sugar to hashes:

```
def foo(key:)
  key
end

args = { key: 'value' }

foo(args)   # Evaluates to foo(key: 'value') => 'value'
foo(**args) # Evaluates to foo(key: 'value') => 'value'
```

Apart from the nice symmetry, is there any practical reason to use double-splats on method calls? (Note that this is distinct from using them on the method definition)

Comment: [A similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289152/what-does-double-splat-operators-do-in-ruby) about `**` in the method's definition contains some relevant info. The comment to the accepted answer talks about the effect of using `**` on arguments a bit.

Comment: You should extract that comment and put it here, answers the question perfectly.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers yes, please do that :)

Comment: I'm on mobile now, it's fine if someone else or you yourself posts it as answer :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The example using a single argument is the degenerate case.

Looking at a nontrivial case, you can quickly see the advantage of having the new `**` operator:

```
def foo (args)
  return args
end

h1 = { b: 2 }
h2 = { c: 3 }

foo(a: 1, **h1)       # => {:a=>1, :b=>2}
foo(a: 1, **h1, **h2) # => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
foo(a: 1, h1)         # Syntax Error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>
foo(h1, h2)           # ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

Using the `**` operator allows us to merge existing hashes (along with separate key-value arguments) at the call site, rather than adding another line (or more) of code to combine all the values into a single hash before passing it as an argument.

(A piece of historical trivia—in Ruby 2.1.1, there was a bug where the splatted hash [would be destructively modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282342/ruby-bug-double-splat-operator-destructively-modifies-hash), though it's since been patched.)