# Ruby ** double star operator

Tags: ruby

> What is ** operator in Ruby?

*Code snippet*

```
1 ** 5 # => 1
43 ** 67 # => 27694053307656599023809257877241042019569010395053468294153499816223586030238186389799480520831161107426185107
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

** is Exponent Operator- It performs exponential (power) calculation. Let me explain by this simple example

2 ** 2 => 2 * 2 => 4

2 ** 3 => 2 * 2 * 2 => 8

2 ** 4 => 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 => 16

2 ** 5 => 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 => 32

so 43 ** 67 => 43 * 43 * 43 * 43 ...............................................................

so it results in such a big number.

To get more details on operatorts http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm

Answer (score 15):

In Ruby, `**` is the exponent operator. I.e., by doing `a**b`, you are raising `a` to the power of `b`. By convention, there are no spaces between the operands.

Example:

```
3**2
#=> 9

2**3
#=> 8
```

Note that the exponent operator has a higher precedence than multiplication and division, just like in mathematics:

```
2 * 2**3 # (2 * 8)
#=> 16

18 / 3**2 # (18 / 9)
#=> 2
```

If you chain the operator, precedence is resolved from the right to the left:

```
2**2**3 == 2**(2**3) # (2^8)
#=> true
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a [`power`](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/numbers/#h-2-2) math operator:

```
2 * 3
# => 6
```

but

```
2 ** 3
# => 8
```

Answer (score 2):

`**` Exponent - Performs exponential (power) calculation on operators

```
1 ** 5 = 1
```

Means it will execute like `1*1*1*1*1` five times

If you will try this

```
2**4 = 16
```

Means it will execute like `2*2*2*2` four times

Answer (score 1):

Its just do it as:

```
2 * 4 => 8
```

and

```
2 ** 4 => 64
```

It treat as power of 2 as (2)^4 => 2*2*2*2