# Please explain Ruby's square root (sqrt) value comparison

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby class that compares the size of two values of x and y by inheriting the built-in module Comparable and sqrt methods. But unfortunately, I don't understand what `def scalar` in the code is calculating?

In the example below, Ruby's execution results in that v1 is greater than v2, but if I print the results of v1 and v2 alone, I get nothing but nonsense. So my second question is, what are the resulting values for v1 and v2?

```
class Vector
  include Comparable              
  attr_accessor :x, :y

  def initialize(x, y)
    @x, @y = x, y
  end

  def scalar
    Math.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)  
  end

  def <=> (other)                 
    scalar <=> other.scalar
  end
end

v1 = Vector.new(2, 6)
v2 = Vector.new(4, -4)
puts v1         #=> #<Vector:0x000055a6d11794e0>
puts v2         #=> #<Vector:0x000055a6d1179490>
p v1 <=> v2     #=> 1
p v1 < v2       #=> false
p v1 > v2       #=> ture
```

Comment: `#<Vector:0x000055a6d11794e0>` isn't nonsense. It's showing the class (Vector) and the memory address (0x000055a6d11794e0) that uniquely identifies that object in Ruby's heap. None of the code here is mutating the values `v1` and `v2` so they are identical to what they were when constructed.

Comment: Do you know what a vector is in mathematics? If not, I suggest you learn about them before trying to use them in code.

Comment: To get a better understanding of your code, try `puts v1.scalar` and `puts v2.scalar`. Since the result of this calculation is used for the comparison, it is much more useful than just `puts v1` and `puts v2`.

Comment: Also : see [Math::hypot](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Math.html#method-c-hypot).

Comment: TPR, if you execute `require 'matrix'` you'll be in trouble because, among other things it loads an existing class [Vector](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html) (at least in some Ruby versions). Be careful to avoid class names that are used by Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what are the resulting values for v1 and v2?

**Override to_s**

```
class Vector 
  def to_s
    "x = #{x} : y = #{y} : scalar = #{'%.6f' % scalar}"
  end
end #Vector
```

And you get this output:

```
puts v1    # =>  x = 2 : y = 6 : scalar = 6.324555
puts v2    # =>  x = 4 : y = -4 : scalar = 5.656854
```

Comment: Probably not a good idea. The OP can see the instance variables and method results  by other means and this result would likely just lead to additional confusion.

Comment: I think it's a great idea to output the attributes state in a user-controlled formatted way, and "to string" is a great place to do it. I love taking advantage of the implied call aspect.   I've found it to be very helpful over the years. If the OP needs referential object equality then put that in there too!  That would be super!  Without contradicting myself I agree that there are "... other means" for outputting various aspects of an object.

Comment: I wonder if potential confusion is mitigated by the fact(?) that `Vector` could be immutable and `scalar` method can become a intiialize-time-calculation instance variable.

Comment: So it would be better to override `inspect`?   ruby-docs Object.inspect =>    *User defined classes should override this method to provide a better representation of obj.*

Comment: Yes that would better however `inspect` conventionally represents state so it would not show the return value of `scalar`, just `@x` and `@y`

Answer (score 2):

`Math.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)` is using [good old Pythagoras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) to calculate the Cartesian distance of the vector's endpoint from the origin, i.e., the length of the vector. For `v1` this is 6.324555320336759, and for `v2` the result is 5.656854249492381.

To inspect a Ruby object use `p` rather than `puts`.

```
p v2   # <Vector:0x0000000109a1eb40 @x=4, @y=-4>
```

Comment: If you're like me and forget that `p` exists, you can also call `.inspect` on any object and also see the object that way.

Comment: what is ```x ** 2 + y ** 2``` means?

Comment: @TPR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987339/ruby-double-star-operator

Answer (score 0):

`scalar` would be better named `magnitude` because it is calculating the length of a vector using the Pythagorean Theorem. If you are unfamiliar with vectors and Pythagorean Theorem, I suggest you study the mathematical concepts here before you continue with much more code. Those concepts will be critical in understanding how they are used in code.