# Double splat and default value in method profile

Tags: ruby

While a method with a default value profile can accept `nil` (besides a hash):

```
def f(options = {})
  options
end

f(hoge: "AAA", foo: "BBB") #=> {:hoge=>"AAA", :foo=>"BBB"}
f(nil) #=> nil
```

A method with double splat raises an error with `nil`:

```
def f(**options)
  options
end

f(hoge: "AAA", foo: "BBB") #=> {:hoge=>"AAA", :foo=>"BBB"}
f(nil) # => wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

When should I use double splat and when should I use `= {}`?

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of [What does a double * (splat) operator do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289152/what-does-a-double-splat-operator-do)

Comment: [ruby - What does a double * (splat) operator do - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289152/what-does-a-double-splat-operator-do) not say error.

Comment: It explains what the `**` operator does. Passing `nil` raises an error as there are no named arguments thus giving the error *wrong number of arguments*.

Comment: [This article - Ruby and double splat operator](http://blog.simplificator.com/2015/03/20/ruby-and-the-double-splat-operator/_) explains the scenario you have mentioned - error is reported for non-hash inputs to double splat operator.  It also explains the typical use of double splat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input to the method MUST be options hash, then, use double splat operator `**`.

Using `options = {}` only declares the default value to be empty hash, however, it does not necessarily guarantee that caller will pass hash - she may pass non-hash values and nil.

If the function was implemented using double splat (`**`) - as evident in examples you have provided - then non-hash and nil values will not be accepted and will be reported as error.