# How do I create a Task using Asana Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby, asana

I'm looking for a really simple "HelloWorld" example of creating a task in Asana using the ruby gem.

Here is what I am trying to run, and I'm just not quite grokking how to pass in the parameters:

```
Asana::Task.create_in_workspace(client,workspace,{ 'name': 'new task' })
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to do:

```
require 'asana'

client = Asana::Client.new do |c|
  c.authentication :access_token, 'personal_access_token'
end

workspace = client.workspaces.find_by_id(12)

client.tasks.create_in_workspace(workspace: workspace.id, options: {}, **data)
```

You can directly pass in a workspace id if you know it before hand. `options` is a hash of request I/O options and `data` is a hash of attributes to post.

You can look into the documentation for more details on them.

You can also look at this [official Hello World example in Ruby](https://asana.com/developers/documentation/examples-tutorials/hello-world) that does not use any SDK.

Comment: So where I struggle is, what is **data?   I saw the method from rdoc, was hoping to see an example...

Comment: @EricPugh Have you checked the API reference for that?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't really grok what **data meant...    I figured out how to just do a CURL style request using the HTTP class isntead of the api

Comment: @EricPugh **data is a hash of attributes, the previous answer just c/ps the information from the source file here: https://github.com/Asana/ruby-asana/blob/master/lib/asana/resources/task.rb . ** is the double-splat operator, which is answered more by this question -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289152/what-does-a-double-splat-operator-do