# block_given? always returns false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I am trying to write the method_missing in Ruby, the method_missing has three parameter as shown

```
def method_missing(mId,*args,&block)
     if (args.empty? && !block_given?)
          puts " Sample One  No arguments were given nor block"
      elsif (!args.entries.empty?)
          puts " there was arguments given"
      elsif (block_given?)
           puts "there was ?code given"
    end 
end
```

The problem calling instance.anything { " block" } always returns **" Sample One  No arguments were given nor block"**. 
it's clear that block_given always returns **false** , but why?

Comment: Can not reproduce: `Foo.new.anything {} # there was ?code given`

Answer (score 2):

You have a bit overcomplicated logic in your method and that's the main reason why it doesn't work according to your expectations. There is no issue with `block_given?`

Also, I don't see any reason in `args.entries.empty?` usage. `args.empty?` gives you the same result, but it looks more clear.

Original method could be rewritten like this, but I would notice that you didn't cover a case when the method can be called with arguments and a block. I don't know if it was an intent or not.

```
def method_missing(mid, *args, &block)
  if args.count > 0
    puts "there were arguments found"
  else
    if block_given?
      puts "there was a code found"
    else
      puts "Sample One  No arguments were given nor block"
    end
  end
end
```

Example which shows that block_given? works properly:

```
class A
  def method_missing(mid, *args, &block)
    p block
    p block_given?
  end
end

A.new.aaaa
nil
false
 => false 

A.new.aaaa { "aaaa" }
#<Proc:0x007fabd313d090@(irb):8>
true
 => true
```

Comment: I wan't to certain procedure to happens when there is an empty 1-empty argument, 2-key-value pair have been passed in the argument, 3-block of code have been passed. 

Consider that the when passing the block of code there would be arguments given which also satisfy case 1.

Comment: If you want to check if keyword arguments were passed in the method then use double splat notation for collecting them into a variable and then refer to this variable of a Hash type. method_missing(mid, *args, **kwargs, &block)

https://flushentitypacket.github.io/ruby/2015/03/31/ruby-keyword-arguments-the-double-splat-and-starsnake.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289152/what-does-a-double-splat-operator-do

Answer (score 0):

This one took a bit of puzzling.

There is nothing wrong with `block_given`, except **your check is nested in an "if else" block**. (That's the Too Long; Didn't Read summary)

You would only see "there was code given" if you passed in no arguments into your function. Passing in arguments triggers the `!args.entries.empty?` if, the if gets matched and any further else statements are not executed.

(Try this at home: try to call your method with no arguments and just a block, then with arguments and a block).

If your expected / desired output is:

 `there was arguments given
there was ?code given`

Then try this method instead. Note how I made your last `elsif` a plain `if` statement:

`def method_missing(mId,*args,&block)
     if (args.empty? && !block_given?)
          puts " Sample One  No arguments were given nor block"
      elsif (!args.entries.empty?)
          puts " there was arguments given"
    end 
    if (block_given?)
      puts "there was ?code given"
    end

end`

Comment: In the last line of the question, the OP writes that calling `instance.anything { " block" }`, i.e. with no arguments but with a block also doesn't work, which does not match up with your explanation.

Comment: Didn't worked it executes also   puts " Sample One  No arguments were given nor block"