# Aptana Studio 3 indicate lines to be error that aren't

Tags: ruby, aptana, aptana3

Aptana thinks the below line is an error but the ruby doesn't complain about it!
[image]

How to fix it?
Or disable the error indicator in Aptana?
Or update the ruby version that Aptana uses to indicate errors to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like your IDE doesn't known the [double splat operator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18289216/2483313) which was introduced in Ruby 2.0.

Comment: @spickermann yeah, it's obvious! The question was `how to make it gone?`