# Array equation explanation

Tags: ruby

I would appreciate if someone could explain why the output of this code:

```
*a, b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a[b-2] + b
```

is `7`. Could anyone please break it down line by line so I understand what's going on here? How does this become `7`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To break anything down line by line one could use REPL:

```
*a, b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
#⇒ [1, 2, 3, 4]

a
#⇒ [1, 2, 3]

b
#⇒ 4
```

Using splat operator, we have decomposed the original array to new array and the single value. Now everything is crystal clear: `a[b-2]` which is `a[2]`, which is in turn `3` (check `a` array.) and b is still `4`.

```
3 + 4
#⇒ 7
```

Comment: So the * operator splits the array at the end and assigns it the last indexed value? And by that, I mean why does *a take the first 3 indexed values and b the last, 4?

Comment: Nope, the splat operator assigns the array on the right to the operand, comma is what decomposes (splits) the original array.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289152/what-does-a-double-splat-operator-do#18289216) is the great source to demistify the splat [and double splat] operator.

Answer (score 2):

`*a, b = [1, 2, 3, 4]` it means  `a = [1,2,3]` and `b = 4` when you do `a[b-2] + b` it will be

```
                +-----------------------+
a[b-2]   + b    |        a[2]           |
a[4-2]   + 4    |          |            |
a[2]     + 4    |  a[1, 2, 3]           |
3        + 4    |    0  1  2 -> index   |
= 7             +-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

when you assign array like this,

```
*a, b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

then it will assign

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

and `b = 4`

Now when you tried to print `a[b-2] + b`

```
a[b - 2] = 3
b = 4
3 + 4 = 7
```

for more understanding use rails console and run line by line.

Answer (score 2):

```
*a, b = [1, 2, 3, 4]

a
 => [1, 2, 3] 

b
 => 4 

a[b-2] // b-2 = 2 find value at index of 2 in a, like a[2] is 3
 => 3 

a[b-2]+b
 => 7
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the splat operator on **a** we are basically letting **a** to scoop up all the other numbers that **b** does not need. So **b** takes one number from the array and **a** takes everything that is left.

```
b = 4 

a = [1,2,3]
```

Now when we do this:

```
a[b-2] + b
```

It translates into:

```
a[4-2] + 4 

a[2] + 4
```

Now we check what number is in position 2 in array **a**.

```
3 + 4 = 7
```