# Does JS's spread syntax appear in other languages?

Tags: javascript, programming-languages, spread-syntax

I first encountered the spread (`...`) syntax in JavaScript, and have grown to appreciate the [many things it can do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Examples), but I confess I still find it quite bizarre.  Is there an equivalent in other languages, and what is it called there?

Comment: Groovy has a spread operator:  http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator.  It's functionality is quite different though.

Comment: To be precise, the spread syntax is *not* an "operator". The term "operator" has a specific meaning in the expression grammar, and the spread syntax isn't part of that.

Comment: The [Go language](http://golang.org) allows this as a means of implementing variadic functions. I prefer its form, where in the "receiving" position (parameters), the `...` comes before the type ident, and in the "sending" positions (arguments), it comes after the values. `func foo(bar string, rest ...string) { /***/ }` ... `foo("bar", myStrings...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in Ruby: the [splat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289152/what-does-a-double-splat-operator-do) operator. It's an asterisk instead of three dots:

```
def foo(a, *b, **c)
   [a, b, c]
end
```

---

```
> foo 10
=> [10, [], {}]
> foo 10, 20, 30  
=> [10, [20, 30], {}] 
> foo 10, 20, 30, d: 40, e: 50
=> [10, [20, 30], {:d=>40, :e=>50}]
> foo 10, d: 40, e: 50
=> [10, [], {:d=>40, :e=>50}]
```

(Copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18289216/8649828))

Comment: And python and perl, I believe. Also using the asterisk.

Comment: JavaScript is the only language I know that uses three dots instead of an asterisk... I think it's because [JavaScript already uses the asterisk somewhere else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function%2A), but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Common Lisp has `&rest` parameters:

```
(defun do-something (&rest params) 
    ...
)
```

Comment: But can you do something like `(+ 1 2 3 ...params)` without using something like `apply`, because that would be pretty sweet.

Comment: @Meow No, Lisp doesn't have that. You can do it with data using backquote: `(1 2 3 ,@params)`, but not with function parameters.

Answer (score 2):

PHP has it too, using the three dots: it is a [new feature of PHP version 5.6](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php).
The operator looks like a ellipsis (…) character but it is not.