# How does the post method work in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post

I come from a Python and Java background with only basic knowledge to CSS, HTML, Ruby and trying to learn web development using Ruby on Rails. I'm trying to follow the tutorial on [Michael Hartl](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#sec-strong_parameters). I do not understand what arguments the `post` method in Listing 7.23 is doing.

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "invalid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      post users_path, params: { user: { name:  "",
                                         email: "user@invalid",
                                         password:              "foo",
                                         password_confirmation: "bar" } }
    end
    assert_template 'users/new'
  end
end
```

From what I trace in the [API](https://apidock.com/ruby/Net/HTTP/post), it takes in 2 non-optional arguments which are both Strings, but in Listing 7.23 there is a sudden hash syntax `params:` in the 2nd argument and this has confused me. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking at the wrong place, the link shows `http.post`. You want the `IntegrationTest post`.

From: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb

```
def post(path, **args)
  process(:post, path, **args)
end
```

And:

```
def process(method, path, params: nil, headers: nil, env: nil, xhr: false, as: nil)
  request_encoder = RequestEncoder.encoder(as)
  headers ||= {}

  # rest
end
```

**Edit: The double splat**

Ruby 2.0 added the keyword arguments **and** the double splat.
A single splat (*) is basically used when you have an unknown number of arguments, and it is passed as `array`.

```
def with_args(*args)
  p args
end

with_args(1,2,"a")
# [1, 2, "a"]
```

The double splat (**) acts like the *, but for keyword arguments:

```
def with_args(**args)
  with_keyword(args)
end

def with_keyword(some_key: nil, other_key: nil)
  p "some_key: #{some_key}, other_key: #{other_key}"
end

with_args(some_key: "some_value", other_key: "other_value")
# "some_key: some_value, other_key: other_value"
with_args(some_key: "some_value")
# "some_key: some_value, other_key: "
```

In ruby, you can call a method without `()` and pass a hash without `{}`, so

```
with_args({some_key: "some_value", other_key: "other_value"})
```

is like writing

```
with_args some_key: "some_value", other_key: "other_value")
```

See this answer: [What does a double * (splat) operator do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289152/what-does-a-double-splat-operator-do) 
and https://medium.freecodecamp.org/rubys-splat-and-double-splat-operators-ceb753329a78

So...

When writing

```
post users_path, params: { user: { name:  "",
                                   email: "user@invalid",
                                   password:              "foo",
                                   password_confirmation: "bar" } }
```

Is calls to process

```
process(:post, users_path, params: { user: { name:  "",
                                   email: "user@invalid",
                                   password:              "foo",
                                   password_confirmation: "bar" } }
```

Meaning in `process`, `params` are the hash

```
{ user: { name:  "",
  email: "user@invalid",
  password:              "foo",
  password_confirmation: "bar" } }
```

It doesn't matter the other keyword args of process, the hash is all `params`, all the other keywords are nil

Hope it makes sense...

Comment: Hi, would you mind enlightening me how the method call to `process` works? I have explained some of my thought process in the answer above, but I can't fully grasp it from the tutorial's context.

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth Sure, what I can.  I edited the answer with the double splat (**) syntax and how the call is passed to process.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. By the assertion, we use the one without the error message, `User.count` is evaluated twice, once at the start, then a 2nd time after executing the code block, which is the `post` function that has some hash parameters as mentioned in this answer. `post` might return something due to `process`, but may also update the count, so we want the console to sound off "red" when there is actually a difference. Not quite sure what the assert's implementation is doing but that's my best bet.

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth You are mostly correct,  the `User.count` is evaluated twice. But the test is to check that the number stays the same, as it is a `post` request to create an **invalid** user. If the `post` request would update the count, it is a bug and the test should fail. If you will look at the implementation, you'll see that `assert_no_difference` just calls to `assert_difference` with 0. The implementation of is: `assert_difference`. https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Testing/Assertions/assert_difference

Comment: I'm actually confused by this: `post :create, article: invalid_attributes` in `assert_no_difference` , `:something` usually means that we have defined a `hash` beforehand and want to access the value of the corresponding key, but where do you find `:create` since it's a method and not some kind of key? The same confusion for `article`. I just interpreted it as what you mentioned just by reading the name, but I can't really reason with the code implementation.

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth. I can see your confusion. I think you are confused with **other** `post` method. `assert_no_difference` takes a block as the third argument and just yields it when it needs to. The doc with the `post :create, article: invalid_attributes` is just an example for a block you can pass, not  necessarily `IntegrationTest`. `:something` is just a symbol which this `post` method can work with. the `post :create` syntax is resemble to `Rspec` https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/controller-spec.  Well maybe i'm wrong but this is how I see it...

Answer (score 3):

Ah! Great question. This line:

`class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`

means that the class is inheriting from `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`.

`ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` is a Rails class. You're looking at the docs for the `Net::HTTP` class, which is a Ruby class.

[Here's the API docs for the  `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` methods.](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html#method-i-post)

Getting mixed up between Ruby and Rails is very common at the start. Rails is the framework, Ruby is the language.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, actually I'm pretty confused by the number of API I have to look into(Rails,Ruby,HTTP,HTML,CSS). Usually I just get stumped at the tutorial and I don't know whether they are overriding an existing class method or they are implementing a new one from nowhere.

Comment: Oh, it's much more readable source than my answer, I just looked at github :)

Comment: And I actually don't understand the API either as shown in the answer before yours, from my basic understanding I think `**args` in `post(path,**args)` does imply the need to pass in a Hash, and the same Hash is being passed into `process`, but then the problem arises when there are so many keyword arguments in `process` and I don't see how the key-value pairs that are contained in the Hash are mapped to the arguments.