# How to deep transform values on Ruby hash

Tags: ruby, hash, transform

I have a hash which looks like this:

```
hash = {
  'key1' => ['value'],
  'key2' => {
    'sub1' => ['string'],
    'sub2' => ['string'],
  },
  'shippingInfo' => {
                   'shippingType' => ['Calculated'],
                'shipToLocations' => ['Worldwide'],
              'expeditedShipping' => ['false'],
        'oneDayShippingAvailable' => ['false'],
                   'handlingTime' => ['3'],
    }
  }
```

I need to convert each value which is a single string inside an array so that it ends up like this:

```
hash = {
  'key1' =>  'value' ,
  'key2' => {
    'sub1' => 'string' ,
    'sub2' => 'string' ,
  },
  'shippingInfo' => {
                   'shippingType' => 'Calculated' ,
                'shipToLocations' => 'Worldwide' ,
              'expeditedShipping' => 'false' ,
        'oneDayShippingAvailable' => 'false' ,
                   'handlingTime' => '3' ,
    }
  }
```

I found this but couldn't get it work
https://gist.github.com/chris/b4138603a8fe17e073c6bc073eb17785

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about something like:

```
def deep_transform_values(hash)
  return hash unless hash.is_a?(Hash)

  hash.transform_values do |val|
    if val.is_a?(Array) && val.length == 1
      val.first
    else
      deep_transform_values(val)
    end
  end
end
```

Tested with something like:

```
hash = {
  'key1' => ['value'],
  'key2' => {
    'sub1' => ['string'],
    'sub2' => ['string'],
  },
  'shippingInfo' => {
                   'shippingType' => ['Calculated'],
                'shipToLocations' => ['Worldwide'],
              'expeditedShipping' => ['false'],
        'oneDayShippingAvailable' => ['false'],
                   'handlingTime' => ['3'],
                   'an_integer' => 1,
                   'an_empty_array' => [],
                   'an_array_with_more_than_one_elements' => [1,2],
                   'a_symbol' => :symbol,
                   'a_string' => 'string'
    }
  }
```

Gives:

```
{
  "key1"=>"value",
  "key2"=>{
    "sub1"=>"string",
    "sub2"=>"string"
  },
  "shippingInfo"=> {
    "shippingType"=>"Calculated",
    "shipToLocations"=>"Worldwide",
    "expeditedShipping"=>"false",
    "oneDayShippingAvailable"=>"false",
    "handlingTime"=>"3",
    "an_integer"=>1,
    "an_empty_array"=>[],
    "an_array_with_more_than_one_elements"=>[1, 2],
    "a_symbol"=>:symbol,
    "a_string"=>"string"
  }
}
```

---

Following your question in the comments, I guess the logic would change a bit:

```
class Hash
  def deep_transform_values
    self.transform_values do |val|
      next(val.first) if val.is_a?(Array) && val.length == 1
      next(val) unless val.respond_to?(:deep_transform_values)

      val.deep_transform_values
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This works well for my use case. However, if I wanted to monkey-patch Hash class, how can I modify this to work with recursion so I can call it on an instance of Hash?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a variation for your case @lacostenycoder.

Comment: this works great. I haven't used `next` with argss before.  Can you point me to documentation for it?

Comment: [This](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) is what the Ruby doc has so far.

Comment: Calling `deep_transform_values` recursively is not needed, as all the values will be visited anyway. The implementation is handled via Active-support so you'll need Rails (or reference the gem).

Answer (score 3):

```
hash = {
  'key1' => ['value'],
  'key2' => {
    'sub1' => ['string'],
    'sub2' => ['string'],
  },
  'shippingInfo' => {
                   'shippingType' => ['Calculated'],
                'shipToLocations' => ['Worldwide', 'Web'],
              'expeditedShipping' => ['false'],
        'oneDayShippingAvailable' => ['false'],
                   'handlingTime' => ['3'],
    }
  }
```

```
def recurse(hash)
  hash.transform_values do |v|
    case v
    when Array
      v.size == 1 ? v.first : v
    when Hash
      recurse v
    else
      # raise exception
    end
  end
end
```

```
recurse hash
  #=> {"key1"=>"value",
  #    "key2"=>{
  #      "sub1"=>"string",
  #      "sub2"=>"string"
  #    },
  #    "shippingInfo"=>{
  #      "shippingType"=>"Calculated",
  #      "shipToLocations"=>["Worldwide", "Web"],
  #      "expeditedShipping"=>"false",
  #      "oneDayShippingAvailable"=>"false",
  #      "handlingTime"=>"3"
  #    }
  #  }
```

Comment: I see my answer is similar to @Sebastian's earlier answer.

Comment: yes very similar except using a switch style but still works. does this translate well as a monkey patch to Hash class?

Answer (score 2):

I noticed a lot of answers with unnecessary recursion. Current version of Ruby `2.7.x` with ActiveSupport (I tested with `6.1.4.4`) will allow you to do this:

**Input data:**

```
hash = {
  'key1' => ['value'],
  'key2' => {
    'sub1' => ['string'],
    'sub2' => ['string']},
  'shippingInfo' => {
    'shippingType' => ['Calculated'],
    'shipToLocations' => ['Worldwide', 'Web'],
    'expeditedShipping' => ['false'],
    'oneDayShippingAvailable' => ['false'],
    'handlingTime' => ['3']}}
```

**Solution:**

```
hash.deep_transform_values do |value|
  # whatever you need to do to any nested value, like:
  if value == value.to_i.to_s
    value.to_i
  else
    value
  end
end
```

The example above will return a typecast String to Integer.

Comment: `Hash#deep_transform_values` requires `active_support` and you need to be on the correct version. Include those details to make this answer valid.

Comment: @lacostenycoder I mentioned ActiveSupport, and ruby version, will for completeness add the version of the gem as well.

Comment: you need these two lines before you instantiate a new hash object. `require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext'`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, consider using an object and allowing the initializer to deconstruct some of the keys for you.

One of the reasons a lot of people like myself started using Ruby in favour of Perl was because of the better expression of objects in place of primitives like arrays and hashes. Use it to your advantage!

```
class ShippingStuff # You've kept the data vague

  def initialize key1:, key2:, shippingInfo:
    @blk = -> val {
      val.respond_to?(:push) && val.size == 1 ?
          val.first :
          cleankeys(val)
    }
    @key1 = cleankeys key1
    @key2 = cleankeys key2
    @shippingInfo = shippingInfo
  end

  attr_reader :key1, :key2, :shippingInfo

  # basically a cut down version of what
  # Sebastian Palma answered with
  def cleankeys data
    if data.respond_to? :transform_values
      data.transform_values &@blk
    else
      @blk.call(data)
    end
  end

end


hash = {
  'key1' => ['value'],
  'key2' => {
    'sub1' => ['string'],
    'sub2' => ['string'],
  },
  'shippingInfo' => {
                   'shippingType' => ['Calculated'],
                'shipToLocations' => ['Worldwide'],
              'expeditedShipping' => ['false'],
        'oneDayShippingAvailable' => ['false'],
                   'handlingTime' => ['3'],
  }
}

shipper = ShippingStuff.new hash.transform_keys!(&:to_sym)
shipper.key1
# "value"
shipper.key2
# {"sub1"=>"string", "sub2"=>"string"}
shipper.shippingInfo
# {"shippingType"=>["Calculated"], "shipToLocations"=>["Worldwide"], "expeditedShipping"=>["false"], "oneDayShippingAvailable"=>["false"], "handlingTime"=>["3"]}
```

In the same vein, I'd even make an `Info` class for the `shippingInfo` data.

You may run into a different problem if `key1` and `key2` are dynamic, but there's ways around that too ([double splat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18289216/335847) for one).

Comment: This is probably a better pattern although a bit more rigid. The data structure here was a non-specific example,

Comment: @lacostenycoder Sure, just wanted to give an alternative, I'm not criticising. The "Just my 2 cents" possibly makes it come off as criticism, probably because people use that before they criticise people, right? I should find a replacement phrase… (o_º)