# Merge hash of arrays into array of hashes

Tags: ruby

So, I have a hash with arrays, like this one:

```
{"name": ["John","Jane","Chris","Mary"], "surname": ["Doe","Doe","Smith","Martins"]}
```

I want to merge them into an array of hashes, combining the corresponding elements.

The results should be like that:

```
[{"name"=>"John", "surname"=>"Doe"}, {"name"=>"Jane", "surname"=>"Doe"}, {"name"=>"Chris", "surname"=>"Smith"}, {"name"=>"Mary", "surname"=>"Martins"}]
```

Any idea how to do that efficiently?

---

Please, note that the real-world use scenario could contain a variable number of hash keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest writing the code to permit arbitrary numbers of attributes. It's no more difficult than assuming there are two (`:name` and `:surname`), yet it provides greater flexibility, accommodating, for example, future changes to the number or naming of attributes:

```
def squish(h)
  keys = h.keys.map(&:to_s)
  h.values.transpose.map { |a| keys.zip(a).to_h }
end
```

```
h = { name:    ["John", "Jane", "Chris"],
      surname: ["Doe", "Doe", "Smith"],
      age:     [22, 34, 96]
    }
```

```
squish(h)
  #=> [{"name"=>"John", "surname"=>"Doe", "age"=>22},
  #    {"name"=>"Jane", "surname"=>"Doe", "age"=>34},
  #    {"name"=>"Chris", "surname"=>"Smith", "age"=>96}]
```

The steps for the example above are as follows:

```
b = h.keys
  #=> [:name, :surname, :age] 
keys = b.map(&:to_s)
  #=> ["name", "surname", "age"] 
c = h.values
  #=> [["John", "Jane", "Chris"], ["Doe", "Doe", "Smith"], [22, 34, 96]] 
d = c.transpose
  #=> [["John", "Doe", 22], ["Jane", "Doe", 34], ["Chris", "Smith", 96]] 
d.map { |a| keys.zip(a).to_h }
  #=> [{"name"=>"John", "surname"=>"Doe", "age"=>22},
  #    {"name"=>"Jane", "surname"=>"Doe", "age"=>34},
  #    {"name"=>"Chris", "surname"=>"Smith", "age"=>96}]
```

In the last step the first value of `b` is passed to `map`'s block and the block variable is assigned its value.

```
a = d.first
  #=> ["John", "Doe", 22] 
e = keys.zip(a)
  #=> [["name", "John"], ["surname", "Doe"], ["age", 22]] 
e.to_h
  #=> {"name"=>"John", "surname"=>"Doe", "age"=>22}
```

The remaining calculations are similar.

Comment: Thanks. This is by far the best answer. Works beautifully :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
h[:name].zip(h[:surname]).map do |name, surname|
  { 'name' => name, 'surname' => surname }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```rb
[h[:name], h[:surname]].transpose.map do |name, surname|
  { 'name' => name, 'surname' => surname }
end
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more like to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

If your dataset is really big, you can consider using [Enumerator::Lazy](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerator/Lazy.html).

This way Ruby will not create intermediate arrays during calculations.

This is how [@Ursus answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61155404/12201472) can be improved:

```rb
h[:name]
  .lazy
  .zip(h[:surname])
  .map { |name, surname| { 'name' => name, 'surname' => surname } }
  .to_a
```

Answer (score 1):

Other option for the case where:

> [..] the real-world use scenario could contain a **variable number** of hash keys

```
h = {
      'name': ['John','Jane','Chris','Mary'],
      'surname': ['Doe','Doe','Smith','Martins'],
      'whathever': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }
```

You could use [Object#then](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-then) with a [splat operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289152/what-does-a-double-splat-operator-do) in a one liner:

```
h.values.then { |a, *b| a.zip *b }.map { |e| (h.keys.zip e).to_h }

#=> [{:name=>"John", :surname=>"Doe", :whathever=>1}, {:name=>"Jane", :surname=>"Doe", :whathever=>2}, {:name=>"Chris", :surname=>"Smith", :whathever=>3}, {:name=>"Mary", :surname=>"Martins", :whathever=>4}]
```

---

The first part, works this way:

```
h.values.then { |a, *b| a.zip *b }
#=> [["John", "Doe", 1], ["Jane", "Doe", 2], ["Chris", "Smith", 3], ["Mary", "Martins", 4]]
```

---

The last part just maps the elements zipping each with the original keys then calling [Array#to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) to convert to hash.

Here I removed the call `.to_h` to show the intermediate result:

```
h.values.then { |a, *b| a.zip *b }.map { |e| h.keys.zip e }
#=> [[[:name, "John"], [:surname, "Doe"], [:whathever, 1]], [[:name, "Jane"], [:surname, "Doe"], [:whathever, 2]], [[:name, "Chris"], [:surname, "Smith"], [:whathever, 3]], [[:name, "Mary"], [:surname, "Martins"], [:whathever, 4]]]
```