# Passing a dynamic set of interpolation arguments to rails-i18n?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

I am upgrading to Rails 6.1.3 and with it, the latest version of `rails-i18n` (1.8.9).

I used to be able to pass a hash of interpolation arguments like this:

```rb
I18n.with_locale(:en) do
  message = I18n.translate("foo", message_args.merge({default: ""}))
end
```

But this now raises:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)):
```

Passing them as arguments [as described](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.1/i18n.html#interpolation) works fine:

```rb
I18n.with_locale(:en) do
  message = I18n.translate("foo", bar: "baz", default: "")
end
```

When checking out the gems `translate` method, it seems it changed between versions:

```rb
# 1.5.3
def translate(*args)
  ...
end

# 1.8.9
def translate(key = nil, throw: false, raise: false, locale: nil, **options)
  ...
end
```

Anyone who knows how I regain my ability to pass a dynamic set of interpolation arguments?

Comment: Have you tried the double splat operator `**`?

Comment: So close, I tried with single. Double splat works. Thanks. If you put it in as answer I'll accept it right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the translate method in the translation helper (https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper.html) accepts a keyword argument hash you need to use the double splat operator `**`. More info in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45338680