# Rails use define_method for assignment method is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a constant

```
TYPES = %w(car truck)
```

I want to define custom assignment methods dynalically

```
TYPES.each do |type|
  define_method "#{type}s=(objects)" do
```

But it doesn't work, 
when I call

```
myobject.cars=objects
```

I am getting an error method doesn't exists although I can trace it

```
puts myobject.methods
```

does have a method

```
cars=(objects)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89650/how-do-you-pass-arguments-to-define-method

Comment: `pluralize` instead of `#{type}s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`define_method` expects method name, not signature.

```
define_method "#{type}s=" do |objects|
  puts objects
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write something like this to make it work:

```
define_method "#{type}s=" do |objects|
```

Answer (score 0):

`define_method(symbol) { block } → symbol`

The actual method is in the block, and the params of block is the params of the actual method. Here is the description from Ruby docs. 
Defines an instance method in the receiver. The method parameter can be a Proc, a Method or an UnboundMethod object. If a block is specified, it is used as the method body. This block is evaluated using instance_eval, a point that is tricky to demonstrate because define_method is private. (This is why we resort to the send hack in this example.)